# Highcharts all js in one package

Tags: highcharts

Can I include all the highcharts js into one main js file and use it in my code.
Eg.

1. **highcharts.js**
2. **highstocks.js**
3. **highcharts-more.js**
4. **exporting.js**

   all these js files into a **highcharts_all.js** file.

Will the code conflict?

Can I do like this.?

Comment: Yes, it will conflict. In short: `Highstock` contains `Highcharts` so use only `highstock.js` file when you want to combine files.

Comment: @PawełFus  Is there a single js file available, which will give all these features.? Instead of including each and every file.

Comment: Yes there is - just see the answer below. Choose which options you need in your charts, and then click "Build". That will create one, concatenated js-file.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom download builder at http://www.highcharts.com/download and choose whatever libs needed . it has stock,export and all options

Comment: Can I add all the JS files into one JS file?

Comment: All files are kept in highcharts.js